# Empty query result problem in the exercise

Tags: sql, subquery, where-clause

I am working on query exercises and I come up with a different query as in the solution, when I run my result in [https://www.win.tue.nl/~hush/playsql/play.html](https://www.win.tue.nl/%7Ehush/playsql/play.html), I have an empty query but the solution gives 91 tuples, below is the question:

***List the customers (id and name) who never bought anything that was on their shopping list for the same date.***

My query:

```
select c.cid, c.cname
from customer C,
     shoppinglist sl, purchase p
where c.cid = sl.cid and c.cid = p.cid and sl.date = p.date and 
       sl.pid not in (select pid
                     from purchase)
```

Solution:

```
SELECT cID, cName
FROM customer
WHERE cID NOT IN
  ( SELECT c.cID FROM customer AS c, shoppinglist AS s, purchase AS p
    WHERE c.cID=s.cID AND c.cID=p.cID AND s.date=p.date and s.pID=p.pID )
```

So I want to know what might go wrong in my query.

Comment: Your query uses the very archaic and deprecated `,` cross join syntax

Comment: @Charlieface, not deprecated, but still ancient and not recommended.

Comment: I'm a little vague on the question.  You have a broken query and you have the correct answer.  The queries are not the same -- and you should learn to use proper, explicit, **standard**, readable `JOIN` syntax.